# CollapsingToolbarLayout title styling

Tags: android, material-design, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-support-design

I'm styling title in CollapsingToolbarLayout. Please, tell me, how to achieve following effect:

1) change font of a title - is that even possible?
2) set bottom margin of a title, when its collapsed
3) break title into two lines, when text is truncated

What I have now, xml with layout:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextViewCollapsed"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextViewExpanded"
        app:expandedTitleMargin="@dimen/article_view_vertical_margin"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="@dimen/article_view_title_default_bottom_margin">
```

and style.xml where I have styles, used by TextAppearance

```
<style name="TextViewCollapsed" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
<item name="android:textSize">@dimen/article_view_title_scrolling_text_size</item>
<item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
<item name="android:layout_marginLeft">@dimen/article_view_vertical_margin</item>
<item name="android:layout_marginBottom">@dimen/article_view_title_default_bottom_margin</item>
</style>

<style name="TextViewExpanded" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/article_view_title_default_text_size</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">@dimen/article_view_vertical_margin</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">@dimen/article_view_title_default_bottom_margin</item>
</style>
```